# Beautiful Soup4 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Tried scraping some numbers from Yahoo Finance, but I keep on getting an AttributeError for one of my soup.find functions. Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

#Switch
source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SWCH?p=SWCH&.tsrc=fin- srch').text
soup = soup(source, 'lxml')
price = soup.find('span', class_=lambda x:x and set(x.split()).issuperset(set("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Fw(b) D(b) Mb(-4px)".split())))
downorup = soup.find('span', class_=lambda x:x and set(x.split()).issuperset(set("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)".split())))
print("Switch stock: " + price.text + ' ' + downorup.text)
```

Comment: `downorup` is ` None`. There is no span with the attributes that you requested. You must check a value returned by `find` before using it.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel Totally irrelevant.

Comment: There is a span: <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)" data-reactid="36">-0.43 (-4.42%)</span

Comment: @JaydeepPatel Wrong, `requests.get(url).text` gives the HTML code (did you try?). The `requests` module does not know how to parse HTML.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel I tried using .content instead of .text, but I nevertheless get the same error.

Comment: @DYZ yes you are right, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second query, "Fz(24px)" must be "Fz(14px)", and there must be no "Pstart(10px)" part:

```
downorup = soup.find('span', class_=lambda x:x and set(x.split())\
               .issuperset(set("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Fz(14px) C($dataRed)".split())))
```

In general, you are using quite a dangerous approach to identify your data. If the formatting of the page changes, you won't find the fields anymore. `"data-reactid"` seems to be a more reliable marker.

Comment: It worked, but what was your logic? Why did I have to change the Fz() and Pstart()?

Comment: All these `class` attributes are not about the data but about its presentation (formatting). Consider searching for data-reactid markers instead.

Comment: I cannot answer a question posted as a comment to my answer. I cannot even understand your code without indentation.

Comment: I tried again, this time with Costco (Which has a stock of 237.74), but get the same stock that Switch has as the result. Why?

Comment: On the line `soup = soup(source, 'lxml')`, you destroyed a reference to the `soup` function (note the same name on the left and on the right). Your _second_ `soup` was not decoded, you probably got an error message.

Comment: I deleted the soup = `soup(source, 'lxml')`. For Costco, and didn't get an error message. Should I keep it, but modify it?

Comment: Don't delete it; fix it.

Comment: So I should change `soup = soup(source, 'lxml')` to ? I'm confused as to what to do.

Comment: You are overwriting a function name by assignment. Change `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup` to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and call `BeautifulSoup` instead of `soup`. In general, one should not attempt to solve complex problems in Python before mastering the basics.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown most probably at the `print` statement.

If the code is not able to find `price` / `downorup` - it will have a value None. 
In that case you are trying to access attributes `price.text, downorup.text` from a None object which throws the exception.

Add a check for None like:

```
if price and downorup:
    print("Switch stock: " + price.text + ' ' + downorup.text)
```

This will go to `print` statement only if both `price` and `downorup` is not None.

Comment: I tried but still got the same error. My error is not that I get "None" as downorup, it's that 'NoneType' has to attribute 'text'.